# Cannot set val when string in double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-quotes

I have the following variable -

```
termText = $("#termBox").val();
```

where `$("#termBox").val()` is equal to - `"\"Test\""`

I then am creating an html object and want to set its value to termText like -

```
<input type="text" id="secondBox" value="' + termText + '">
```

However this is not working. The odd thing is when `$("#termBox").val()` does not have double quotes in it i.e. `"Test"` (in javascript debugger is adding the quotes to show it is a string), this works fine and populates `secondBox` value perfectly.

I dont want to escape double quotes from the string as they are required as there has to be a definition between when a user enters `"Term"` or `Term` however this is not working for double quotes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use something else other than quotes.

Comment: the quotes are required, if a user enters double quotes around the string, then they have to be present in the secondBox val as stated.

Comment: I understand it is needed to indicate something, what I mean is since you are having this issue, can you use a different indicator? I am not sure if `value=""term""` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are allowing your users to enter delimiters, but set the value with `.val()` instead:

```
var input = $('<input type="text" id="secondBox"/>').val(termText);
```

This way jQuery takes care of any delimiting required.

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape it with html equivalent when you create input.

```
<input type="text" id="secondBox" value="' + termText.replace(/\"/g,"&quot;") + '">
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the quotes will result in raw quotes when accessing the value.

Console:

```
var termText = "\"Test\"";
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('value', termText);
console.log(input.value);
console.log(input.outerHTML);
```

Output:

```
"Test"
<input value="&quot;Test&quot;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not allow your users to enter double, single quotes or back slashes. They are a few of the dangerous characters that you should be scrubbing form user enter fields. if you need the quotes latter you should add them backing yourself behind the scenes. You will be opening yourself up for Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

You could achieve what you are looking to do by just taking the user input; cleaned of dangerous characters; and them just pass that to the value of the new input. Just as TrueBlueAussie mentioned. With a little revision.

```
var termText = $("#termBox").val();
var input = $('#secoundBox').val(termText);
```

Comment: Here is one of the best references on preventing SXX  attacks. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet